# MySQL Trigger Function (between 3 different tables)

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I have 3 tables (written as important parts, not all data):

**tableDeviceStatus**:

```
device_id    status
---------    ------
device01     15
device02     20
```

**tableDeviceTrigger**:

```
device_id    device_operator   device_param   triggered_device   command
---------    ---------------   ------------   ----------------   -------
device01     >                 22             device80           1
device01     <                 18             device87           0
device02     =                 1              device89           1
```

**tableDeviceCommand**:

```
device_id    command
---------    -------
device80 
device87
device89
```

Flow:

- When *tableDeviceStatus* updated I will create trigger (AFTER)
- If a device updated, check *tableDeviceTrigger* and compare by operators and update *tableDeviceCommand*

For example:

- device01 updated as 25.
- there is 2 comparison. Check both and since 25>22, update *tableDeviceCommand*.device80 as 1.

I have tried trigger but couldn't solve search, compare and execute. (because a device can take more than one comparison. I nearly created for one row but could't formulize for like for each rows and execute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! If I understand correctly, for each new row entered in `tableDeviceStatus`, you want to test each row with a matching @device_id in tableDeviceTrigger.

For each matching row in tableDeviceTrigger, you test if it meets the requirements (`@status @device_operator @device_param is TRUE`). For each row that meets these requirements, you add a row in tableDeviceCommand with the `@triggered_device` and `@command`.

Does something like this work?

```
INSERT INTO tableDeviceCommand (device_id, command)
-- maybe REPLACE INTO or UPDATE depending on your requirements
(
  SELECT tdt.triggered_device, tdt.command
  FROM tableDeviceStatus tds
  INNER JOIN tableDeviceTrigger tdt on tds.device_id = tdt.device_id
  WHERE
    (tdt.device_operator = ">" and tds.status > tdt.device_param) OR
    (tdt.device_operator = "<" and tds.status < tdt.device_param) OR
    (tdt.device_operator = "=" and tds.status = tdt.device_param)
    -- add additional ORs to test the comparison specified by device_operator
)
```

Comment: thank you. I will add this technique into trigger function.